# Difference between rect_size and rect_min_size in godots control nodes

Tags: user-interface, game-engine, godot

I am trying to understand the control nodes in Godot and i have one incredibly annoying problem. I do not entirely understand the relationship between the rect_size and rect_min_size. When i try to organize my ui elements they keep changing their values and thereby moving to places i do not want them to be.

What is the relationship between these two variables and how can i solve the problem that they keep changing?

Answer (score 1):

`rect_min_size` is the minimum size that the control's rect can be sized. In other words, the control should never get smaller than `rect_min_size`.

`rect_size` is the actual size of the control's rect.

I recommend looking into [Containers](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/3.1/classes/class_container.html) and a control's size flags. HBoxContainer and VBoxContainer's are great tools for laying out a responsive UI.

Another tip: When you are frequently changing the UI with multiple levels deep of Controls use `find_node()` rather than `get_node()`. This way you don't have to keep updating the paths after moving around the Control nodes.

Example:

```
onready var status_label: Label = find_node('status_label') as Label
```

Hope this helps.